# not plausible MySQL error: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

i encounter a weird behaviour of MySQL. The query:

```
INSERT INTO `request_outsources` (`id`, `date`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

returns the error:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

All three columns exist and can be NULL. Even on the Insert-Mask of PHPMyAdmin i getting this error. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

//EDIT

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `request_outsources`
```

returns

```
CREATE TABLE `request_outsources` (
`id` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`date` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`time` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Is any colom is auto incremented?  Please send table structure

Comment: no all columns are VARCHAR and allowed to be NULL. I dont get why the count should be different. 3 == 3?

Comment: This fiddle doesn't throw any error: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rYwgJypucvqtF23WBrWxeH/1

I would try adding back-quotes around `date` and `time` just in case, but I'm not sure it will help in your case

Comment: Are those 3 the only columns of your table? What is your primary key?

Comment: @Pepper in my original query there are back-quotes around the field-names.

Comment: @Pepper there is also no primary key. And yes those are the only three columns of the table

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE request_outsources`  edit the question with the table structure..   Question is incomplete and unclear without table structure...

Comment: Maybe it's something be related to your global/session settings? (Just throwing the idea, I actually have no clue...) I updated the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rYwgJypucvqtF23WBrWxeH/4) if someone wants to experiment with it

Comment: @RaymondNijland I edited my question with the SHOW CREATE TABLE return.

Comment: Wierd i don't see a reason why it fails.. BUT you had `AUTO_INCREMENT=45027` in the structure meaning it worked before? Also the `AUTO_INCREMENT=45027` part not visible annymore also not in the revisions which is wierd..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes there was an auto-incement field. but i broke it down piece for piece until the version of my question. and the error still remains.

Comment: i meant something else with `AUTO_INCREMENT=45027`, i meant did it work before the error because `AUTO_INCREMENT=45027` indicates errorless inserted records..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes it worked before. but now i get this error on my local machine and even on my online-server. so i tried to simplify the query to get to the jizz...but event that simple version of the table fails. i almost looks like an mysql bug. but i dont know

Comment: *" i almost looks like an mysql bug. but i dont know"* No idea [your code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hyDAbvhEioYbvLWVw25KLA/2) runs on MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 8 without troubles there...   Can you do `SELECT @@sql_mode;` and paste the result here ?

Comment: if you try to insert only one column: `INSERT INTO request_outsources (time) VALUES (NULL);`, do you get the same error? or even no columns at all: `INSERT INTO request_outsources () VALUES ();`

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes i can: `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: @Pepper yes it fails with only one column and also with no columns. that can't be right?

Comment: Yes like expected the [sql_mode](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hyDAbvhEioYbvLWVw25KLA/3) also does not matter and not getting the error..  Can you do `SELECT VERSION()` it indeed seams more and more like you are running a bugged MySQL version...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what is causing this issue... [updated fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rYwgJypucvqtF23WBrWxeH/5)

Comment: But "offtopic":  `date varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
time varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL`  should ideally be replaced with `column_name DATETIME DEFAULT NULL`    as that uses less bytes to store vs `VARCHAR` especially when using utf8.. Also a `DATETIME` datatype makes more sense to store a date and a time..

Comment: @RaymondNijland. it was type DATE and TIME. but like i said. the version of my question is the absolute minified simplified.

Comment: Seems impossible I would a) restart the mysql server and b) check for triggers on this table. (b is my bet)

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table?